# Are any permissions required to register users with phone numbers in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I will publish an app on Appstore. In this application, the user will log into the application using his phone number and become a member. I will publish this application from my personal developer account. Do I need to show any certificate to Firebase for this? Since I will publish this application from my personal developer account, can I register a user with a phone number?

When I register the user with my phone number, will Google ask for a company account from me?